# Rails mulitple AR operations (min, max, avg.. ) on same query object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to perform multiple calculations using one query to price_histories table, and finally render some statistics using those prices like average, minimum and maximum etc.

**price_histories_controller.rb**

```
price_stats = PriceHistory.where('created_at >= ? AND cast(item_id as integer) = ?', 1.day.ago, params['item_id'])

avg_array = price_stats.group(:day).average(:price).to_a
min_array = price_stats.group(:day).min(:price).to_a
max_array = price_stats.group(:day).max(:price).to_a
count_array = price_stats.group(:day).count(:price).to_a
```

This is the relevant code that causes the error, i'd like to perform some calculations on a set of grouped data but after the first calculation is done, I keep getting

> TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)

Ideally I would end up with an object like this one to be rendered:

```
@all_stats = {
  average: avg_array,
  min: min_array,
  max: max_array,
  count: count_array
}

render json: @all_stats
```

This sums up my intentions pretty well, I'm new to ruby and I'd like a solution or a better approach which I'm sure there are.

The following code works fine and I'd like anyone to point me in the right direction to finding out why this works fine and when adding and extra calculation it doesn't:

```
    price_stats = PriceHistory.where('created_at >= ? AND cast(item_id as integer) = ?', 1.day.ago, params['item_id'])

    avg_array = price_stats.group(:day).average(:price).to_a
```

and leads to:

```
{
  "average": [
      [
         null,
         "11666.666666666667"
      ],
      [
         "24/4/2019",
         "11666.666666666667"
      ],
      [
          "24",
          "11666.6666666666666667"
      ],
      [
          "2051",
          "11666.6666666666666667"
      ]
  ],
  "min": [],
  "max": [],
  "count": []
}
```

Other approach:

```
      PriceHistory.select(
        "AVG(price) AS average_score, 
        MIN(price) AS average_min, 
        MAX(price) AS average_max, 
        COUNT(*) AS price_count"
      ).where(
        'created_at >= ? AND cast(item_id as integer) = ?', 
        1.day.ago, params['item_id']
      ).group(:day)
```

Error:

> ArgumentError (Call `select' with at least one field):

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
PriceHistory.where(
  'created_at >= ? AND cast(item_id as integer) = ?',
  1.day.ago,
  params['item_id']
).group(:day).select(
  "SUM(price) AS sum_price",
  "MAX(price) AS max_price",
  "MIN(price) AS min_price",
  "AVG(price) AS avg_price",
  "day"
)
```

This will return you an array of records, each which has methods `day`, `sum_price`, `max_price`, `min_price`, and `avg_price`.

Note that the names of the SQL functions might be different based on your db

Comment: tried your solution and --> ERROR:  column "price_histories.day" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. If i remove "day", i get "#<ArgumentError: Call `select' with at least one field>". which is what i was getting with this other approach: i edited the question with the other approach and error! Thank you for answering!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `group(:day)`.

Comment: Can you use Arel to make this database independent?

Comment: @br3nt Hopefully it could be done, but I don't know how. I'd be curious to know though, that's a good point you raise

Comment: @br3nt I tried looking through the source code of a method like [sum](https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/sum), it looks like it eventually goes to [construct_calculation_sql](https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/construct_calculation_sql) which makes an entire SELECT statement for that single operation. But, I don't know anything about how Arel differs from ActiveRecord, so _maybe_ it's possible?

Comment: @max Something like this should work: `PriceHistory.arel_table[: price].maximum.as('max_count').to_sql`

Comment: `PriceHistory.where(item_id: params['item_id']).where(PriceHistory.arel_table[: created_at].gteq(1.day.ago)).group(:day).select(PriceHistory.arel_table[: price].maximum.as('max_count').to_sql, ...)`